# How to use putting validation message underneath a control using backbone validation

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am using [backbone.validation.js](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation)

I am able to implement this as shown in the demo [here](http://thedersen.com/projects/backbone-validation/examples/)

[image]

So, I am able to show the error messages next to the field. I want to be able to show these message underneath the controls.

I checked the HTML generated for these messages, it reads

```
<span class="help-inline error-message">
    Please provide your first name
</span>
```

I tried doing through CSS, it could do it but it gets a little messy. Wanted to know if there is already a provision for this which I may have missed.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try to remove the `help-inline` class.
According to the documentation the `help-inline` class is a feature:

> You may use `<input .... data-error-style="inline">` in your form to force rendering of `<span class="help-inline">`

So all you have to do is to remove/change the `data-error-style` attribute.

Comment: it doesnt help, it still renders the error message to the left of the fields :'(